# Wordpress Plugin in error for user Pro

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

Hey can anyone explain to me why I get this error when I try to save the registration form.

Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in /home/wolf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/userpro/admin/admin-functions.php on line 252

Here is the line in question for the php.

```
/** List all groups **/
function userpro_admin_list_groups(){
    global $userpro;
    $output = null;
    $groups = $userpro->groups;

    unset($groups['register']);
    unset($groups['edit']);
    unset($groups['view']);
    unset($groups['login']);
    unset($groups['social']);

    $array = array(
        'register' => __('Registration Fields','userpro'),
        'edit' => __('Edit Profile Fields','userpro'),
        'login' => __('Login Fields','userpro'),
        'social' => __('Social Fields','userpro')
    );
```

IF anyone can shed some liht on this that would be great as far as i see theres nothing written wrong, and even the plugin maker is scrating his head on this....

the config for the php is 5.4
And the Apache is 2.4
Mysql is running 5.6

Comment: Not actually seen this error before myself, but I'd guess `$groups` is a string, not an array

Comment: Is there a fix to it?

Comment: or just try and do a 'if(isset($groups['register'])) unset $groups['register'];' etc ? First try 'print_r($groups)' to see if it is indeed an array.